# I want to create a header and footer which is used in multiple page..can i write code once and call it on multiple page in xamarin forms

Tags: forms, xamarin

Same code is need write again again on.is there any way to solve so write code once and reused that code

Comment: Check https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you post anything again. Your question is horribly designed. The title is way too long, your tags seem flawed (forms is not xamarin.forms btw). What have you tested so far? which code are you talking about? I assume its C#, so learn about inheritance...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the same code on different platforms, you can use portable class library.
See [this post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0b73e1/introduction-to-portable-class-library-pcl/)
For example, you can create two separate files for header and footer, and use them where you want.

Comment: I am using portable class library..but footer code i have to write multiple page which is the same for all.

Comment: @Mavu I don't understand, why do you need to write footer for every page if you use pcl...
Create a separate class in your pcl for footer and include it where you need.

Comment: @mavu any news? Did you achieve the result?

Comment: Glad to hear it @mavu.